# logistic mixed Null model outcome In R and SAS

Tags: logistic, mixed-model

I have fitted a null mixed model to my binary outcome variable for 96 groups. I have included SAS and R codes and outcomes. The problem for me is that the outcomes from two software do not match. I will appreciate it very much for your insight.
Thanks

**SAS code:**

    `format db db.;
run;`

```
ods output fitstatistics=fitNull;
```

title "Model Null,No covariate";
proc glimmix data=data noclprint;
class group ;
model db = / solution link=logit dist=binary  cl ;
random intercept / type=un subject=group;
format db db.;
weight WEIGHT;
run;

Output:
Fit Statistics 
-2 Res Log Pseudo-Likelihood   26057026 
Generalized Chi-Square         26088235 
Gener. Chi-Square / DF         237.31

Covariance Parameter Estimates 
Cov Parm Subject  Estimate  Standard
Error 
UN(1,1) Group     0.08987     0.01299

Solutions for Fixed Effects 
Effect     Estimate StandardError DF   t Value   Pr >|t|  Alpha Lower Upper 
Intercept -2.5054   0.03046       96   -82.26    <.0001   0.05 -2.5659 -2.4450

**R code:**

    `MOdelNull <- glmer(db ~ 1 +(1|Group),data=data,family = binomial,weights=WEIGHT)`

**Outcome:**
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 25118593  25118612 -12559294  25118589    109930

Random effects:
 Groups        Name        Variance    Std.Dev.
 Group        (Intercept) 0.06343      0.2519
Number of obs: 109932, groups:  Group, 97

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.35310    0.02538  -53.31   <2e-16 ***